# Android, updating the recyclerview UI to reflect time in a format I prefer(Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

[image]

The image above is a New's application, to display the news I am using a recyclerview, however I can't seem to get the time format right. For example, I want the time to be shown in minutes if it is less than `60` minutes and in hours if it is more than or equal to `60` minutes.

Here is the code in my `recyclerview` adapter.

```
            val currentTimeInHours = Instant.now().atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"))

        val newsTimeInHours = Instant.parse(time).atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"))

        val hoursDifference = Duration.between(currentTimeInHours, newsTimeInHours)


val hoursAgos = if(hoursDifference.toMinutes() < 60){
                hoursDifference.toMinutes().toString().substring(1) + " minutes ago"
            }else{
             hoursDifference.toHours().toString().substring(1) + " hour ago"
            }

//Assigning the logic to the textview
holder.tvPublishedAt.text = hoursAgos
```

All of these code is located in the `onbindviewholder` method within the adapter.

Comment: What are you using the "substring(1)" for ?

Comment: there is a `-` that comes along with the value from the `hoursDifference` variable, hence in order to get rid of that, I `substring` it

Comment: The - is the minus sign. You better use abs() to get the absolute value. abs(hoursDifference.toMinutes()).toString()